# How to use another variable within JSON data?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
login_info = {
    'user': {
        'email': 'email',
        'password': 'password',
        'validator': '{validator}',
    },
}
    


def get_tokens():
    print(style.YELLOW + f'[{datetime.now()}] => getting tokens[]')
    request_token = requests.get('APIURL/request_token')
    validator = request_token.text

    
    submit_login = requests.post('API URL', headers=login_headers, json=login_info)
    submit_login = submit_login.json()
    print(style.YELLOW + f'[{datetime.now()}] => posting login[]')
    print(submit_login['authenticationToken'])
    
    if submit_login.status_code == 200:
        print(style.GREEN + f'[{datetime.now()}] => submitted[submit_login.status_code][')
    else:
        print(style.RED + f'[{datetime.now()}] => error posting login[{submit_login.status_code}][{submit_login.response}]')
        
get_tokens()
```

Hello, I have a request which calls for a token to then use as a `validator` within another piece of json data then posted to another request. how can i make it so the `validator` fetched can be used within the `login_info` json data. thanks!

Comment: Try `login_info['user']['validator'] = validator`

Comment: so would I leave the json blank?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you defining the `login_info` dict before you know all its contents?  Define it inside the function:

```
def get_tokens():
    request_token = requests.get('APIURL/request_token')

    login_info = {
        'user': {
            'email': 'email',
            'password': 'password',
            'validator': request_token.text,
        },
    }

    submit_login = requests.post('API URL', headers=login_headers, json=login_info)
    ...
```

Comment: I get error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'login_info' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @scraps Then you didn't follow my example.

Comment: oh yes. i had request_token defined as something else but even with that validator it seems there is another `cookie` that is required because I am getting a 401 response so i'll work on that but thanks anyways